# AlarmManager Android 4.4.2 bug

Tags: android

In my app I have a service and I use AlarmManager in this way:

```
AlarmManager am =(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, getIntent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);      
long mills = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
mills += time;   
am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, mills, pi);
```

And here is the receiver for my intent of the am:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Timer3GOn.intentExtra)) {         
    //some code     
}
```

Here is how my app works: 
when screen goes on (i receive `Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT` ) i set an AlarmManager that after a certain amount of time sends my intent `Timer3GOn.intentExtra` that is received by my class.

All this works fine except in Android 4.4.2 (haven't tested in 4.4.1 yet, but in 4.4 it works well). Only in android 4.4.2 if I delete my app from the "recent app list" of the device, the am is set properly but the intent is never received by my app; plus all the code in the service remains like stuck. So my app stops working but service remains in the RAM.

The problem doesn't start when I delete my app from recent app list, but only after I do that and the AlarmManager is set. How to resolve the problem?

P.S. in my app i have a `CountDownTimer` in the same class with the same context and it works well!

P.P.S. I've noticed that whatsapp has the same problem, if you delete it from recent apps, all the incoming messages don't being delivered until i open the program. It's just me or this happens to all 4.4.2 android versions?

Comment: Long value stored in preference

Comment: If you set your app with `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in the manifest, it works fine ?

Comment: Are you using `ApplicationContext` as the context for the AM ?

Comment: The context of the AM is from BroadcastReceiver `public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` because i start the AM after `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`

Comment: `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` is a nice workaround, but if the activity is displayed and "recent apps" is open, it still possible to delete the activity from it (android bug?).

Comment: I'm not quite sure the connection between the 'recent apps' and the  `AlarmManager` is as strong as you decribe..I have similar issue with my app and 4.4.2 but I don't think `recent apps` has something to do with it.

Comment: i'm pretty sure of it because i've tested my app on 4.4.2 for several days and if i don't delete it from "recent apps" it keep works well, when i delete app from "recent apps" it keep works untill first AM has finished (in my case is really short time). Maybe is something about context that erasing app from recent list the "context" is cleared in some way...

Comment: Sorry, I really not sure I understand the machine state here, can you please edit and write what happens exactly in each case ? What is 'my app running'? Is it the alarmManager going off?

Comment: Sorry, i hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Starting android 4.4 you have to use `setExact()` in order to execute alarms in accurate time.
Otherwise it'z the OS decision when to execute your alarm.

Comment: Yes, but in accordance with [link](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html) "When you set your app's targetSdkVersion to "19" or higher" my app targetSdkVersion is 17 so i don't have to use `setExact()`. I've tried to set targetSdkVersion to 19 and use `setExact()` but Eclipse give me this error "The method setExact(int, long, PendingIntent) is undefined for the type AlarmManager"

Comment: You have to set SDK 19 as your target version through the project properties.

Comment: If i set SDK to 19 (i forgot to set in project properties) and use `setExact()` the problem still the same. :(

Comment: Do you use the `receiver` from  a library ?

Comment: the receiver is in my own class `public class ScreenBR extends BroadcastReceiver {`